# Is it possible in ASP MVC to make a dropdown list that contains a checkbox list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

So I'm working on a scrum project thingy for a c# course, and I need to make a filter form for a list of articles, so one can choose as many or as little categories to show the articles of. I did that with a viewmodel containing all the things to filter by, including a list of viewmodels that have a bool property to show if theyre checked. And I show that list in a sequence of checkboxes with the name of the category next to it.

```
@for (Int32 i = 0; i < this.Model.AvailableCategories.Count; i++)
        {
            <label asp-for="@Model.AvailableCategories[i]">
                <input asp-for="@Model.AvailableCategories[i].Selected" /> @Model.AvailableCategories[i].CategoryName
            </label>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AvailableCategories[i].CategoryId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AvailableCategories[i].CategoryName)
        }
```

Now, they asked to put that list in a dropdown list, so it seems like that should be totally possible, or they wouldn't have asked for it. But I can't seem to find any way to actually make a dropdown list that allows me to select multiple things, let alone show checkboxes.

So, any tips? How can I make this work?

Comment: Using `<select multiple` (without the checkboxes); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783700/asp-net-core-razor-pages-select-multiple-items-from-ienumerable-dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

Given the coursework nature, I'll leave this as high level steps. I'll assume the objective is using regular HTML - you have more options if JS libraries are permitted.

1. Given that you want to render as a select list element, start there. There are ASP tag helpers to facilitate this.
2. With #1 complete, you can apply your own additional HTML properties to the element. There is a `multiple` attribute available for select lists in HTML (although it doesn't behave exactly like the single select list anymore in terms of the dropdown).

> From W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple
>
> ```
> <select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
>     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
>     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
>     <option value="opel">Opel</option>
>     <option value="audi">Audi</option>
> </select>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo to make a dropdown list that contains a checkbox list:
View:

```
<div id="list" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
    <span class="anchor">Select Categories</span>
    <ul class="items">
        @for (Int32 i = 0; i < this.Model.AvailableCategories.Count; i++)
        {
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.AvailableCategories[i].Selected" />@Model.AvailableCategories[i].CategoryName
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AvailableCategories[i].CategoryId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AvailableCategories[i].CategoryName)
            </li>



        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Style:

```
<style>
    .dropdown-check-list {
        display: inline-block;
    }

        .dropdown-check-list .anchor {
            position: relative;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 5px 50px 5px 10px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

            .dropdown-check-list .anchor:after {
                position: absolute;
                content: "";
                border-left: 2px solid black;
                border-top: 2px solid black;
                padding: 5px;
                right: 10px;
                top: 20%;
                -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
                -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
                -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
                transform: rotate(-135deg);
            }

            .dropdown-check-list .anchor:active:after {
                right: 8px;
                top: 21%;
            }

        .dropdown-check-list ul.items {
            padding: 2px;
            display: none;
            margin: 0;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-top: none;
        }

            .dropdown-check-list ul.items li {
                list-style: none;
            }

        .dropdown-check-list.visible .anchor {
            color: #0094ff;
        }

        .dropdown-check-list.visible .items {
            display: block;
        }
</style>
```

js:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var checkList = document.getElementById('list');
            checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function (evt) {
                if (checkList.classList.contains('visible'))
                    checkList.classList.remove('visible');
                else
                    checkList.classList.add('visible');
            }
        })
    </script>
}
```

result:

[image]